# Shiny issues when rendering html page

Tags: r, shiny, render

I'm new to shiny and I'm encountering an issue which doesn't let me view the whole graph and table as the web page is cut into a half. Do you know why this happen?

edit: I have a slider to go up and down the page but I'd like to see it at full resolution.

example:

```
t = data.frame(x = sample(c('a1','b1','b2'), size = 720, replace = TRUE),
               date = sample(seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-01'), by = 'month'), replace = TRUE, size = 720),
               tx = runif(720),
               ty = runif(720))

ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title
  titlePanel("Hello"),

  # selector for the graph
  shiny::selectInput(inputId = 'selector', label = 'Selector'
                     ,choices = unique(t$x))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    ta = t %>% filter(x== input$selector& date >= '2014-01-01') %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(ty = sum(ty)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(data = ta)+
      geom_line(aes(x = date, y = ty, colour = 'red'))+
      theme_bw()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is `t`? This example is not reproducible.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks I'm sorry i forgot to add the data frame construction. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just adding

```
options = list(height = 1080)
```

at the end of the shinyApp command, as shown below:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = 1080))
```